# On a web server, when is it worth it to do asychronous I/O?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, webserver

I'm working on a web site that is expected attract a large number of users within a short time, and we want to minimize the number of servers required on the farm.  Handling requests can involve local I/O, sql server requests to a single db server, and http requests to an external website.  My first thought was that we definitely need to implement all I/O asynchronously, but after [some more reading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx) I'm not as certain.

I understand that asynchronous calls to a sql server can simply move the bottleneck to the db server.  Since our db requests should be fast anyway, it might be better to keep them synchronous so that requests queue up across multiple web servers instead of the single db server.

For accessing the local file system, I suspect the same thing might also be true (just moving the bottleneck further down into the OS.)  Would there be a good reason to do local file I/O asynchronously for reading/writing one or two files that are 25K-150K in size per web request?

Accessing external websites is the one case where asynchronous requests might still make sense.  The external service is not likely to become a bottleneck (it is much more scalable than our site needs to be), and will introduce longer delays (compared to db and local files) since the connection is across the Internet.  This should also be a relatively rare situation, maybe 5 percent of all requests.

I don't have enough experience to have a good "gut feeling" on these issues, and while we will need to do some performance testing, we don't have time to extensively test all the possible implementations.

It probably doesn't make a difference, but the software stack in this case is ASP.Net MVC 3 and Sql Server.

For a sense of the scope, we need to be ready for around 10 million users over two weeks, probably with an early spike.  The site involves uploading and returning files of around 150K, and maintaining some simple records in a db.  We're hosting it behind a CDN, but my concern is mostly with the file and db I/O, and the calls to an external website.

Any thoughts on where asynchronous calls would actually help in this application?

Comment: "asynchronous" does not automagically mean "faster."

Comment: I understand that it won't speed up an individual request, but theoretically it can improve scalability by helping prevent thread starvation on the server's thread pool.  (Where requests that are just waiting for I/O can tie up the pool and prevent simple requests from going through, even though plenty of CPU is available.)

Comment: i assume you will never have this type of load that this will get a problem. i run a high traffic page using asp.net mvc3 and worried if it will scale, now our webservers are bored the most time :-) scale & optimize when it's required, not before...

Comment: Snoopy: That's good to hear.  In this case though the website is for a promotion, and the traffic is expected to spike very early, so we'll have very little time to make adjustments of the fly.  For reference, we need to be ready for around 10 million users over two weeks, possibly with most of them in the first few days.

Comment: if i just count 12 hours, this is around 1000 users per minute, means 16,66 concurrent users when using a single webserver. That's nothing :-)

Comment: Snoopy: Thanks for the feedback.  I think I'll start by increasing the IIS max request limits to prevent premature "server is busy" errors during minor spikes.  It looks like there's a good chance that will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async helps if you wait for a long time. E.g. you start a request via http or socket to a service and wait 15 seconds for response. In this case it makes no sense to block a thread for waiting as more threads are required which costs context switches and cost a lot of memory.

in the case of databases async makes sense for writing statistic records, where you have a fire and forget and dont wait for the response. In any other case i would analyze why the db is too slow that you think you require async.

normally i would say, async stuff heavily increases complexity, and in my personal experience it was in many cases not worth the effort. I would optimize everywhere else, using caching etc before going async.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess maybe my question boils down to How long must the expected I/O time be for it to make sense to make the call asynchronous?  If a server is handling hundreds of hits per second, and you want to maximize its capacity, would async calls make sense for requests that take 2 sec, or even a fraction of a sec?  The notion being that any I/O usually takes orders of magnitude longer than simply returning a page from RAM.

Comment: i guess there is no country lore for such stuff ;-) if you go async i would wait for .net 4.5 and mvc4. we saved a lot of cpu by offloading the ssl traffic to a loadbalancer with an asic chip.

Comment: Unfortunately we need to deploy in a couple weeks, so I could use some country lore!